# Jquery / CSS: Change the css of a cloned tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to clone a hidden table row, paste it and make it visible. For some reason the tr stays hidden. I've tried different ways but in the end I can not find a solution.

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addproduct').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = document.getElementById('hiddenTemplate').cloneNode(true);
    $('#hiddenTemplate').after(item);
    $('#hiddenTemplate').css("visibility", visible);

  });
});
```

```css
#hiddenTemplate {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addproduct" class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</button>

<table id="tableProducts">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><b>SKU</b>:</td>
      <td><b>Default Quantity</b>:</td>
      <td><b>Position</b>:</td>
      <td><b>Is Default?</b></td>
      <td><b>User Defined?</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="hiddenTemplate">
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="sku">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="quantity">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="position">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" id="isDefault">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="userdefined">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you clone `$('#hiddenTemplate')` you have two items with that ID. Your code will not work as expected unless IDs are unique.

Comment: `item.removeAttribute("id")`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing quotes around `visible`:

```
$('#hiddenTemplate').css("visibility", "visible");
```

(and as said in the comments, use a class rather than an id)

Comment: Works, but if i fill those textboxes and then create a new one, the data from the cloned template is getting copyed

Answer (score 0):

There where 3 misstakes in your code

1. remove Attribute id
2. $('#hiddenTemplate').css("visibility", "visible");
3. see 2 and do it on `$(item)`

```js
$( document ).ready(function()
{
    $('#addproduct').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var item = document.getElementById('hiddenTemplate').cloneNode(true);
        item.removeAttribute('id');
        $('#hiddenTemplate').after(item);
        $(item).css("visibility", "visible");
    });
});
```

```css
#hiddenTemplate
{
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addproduct" class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</button>

<table id="tableProducts">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>SKU</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Default Quantity</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Position</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Is Default?</b></td>
            <td><b>User Defined?</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="hiddenTemplate">
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="sku">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="quantity">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="position">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" id="isDefault">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="userdefined">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```